# Keeping one button active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to make status buttons. Basically people show their current status with this. I want the currently selected status to have the css btn:selected class. But then when you press another button that button would take the selected class and the other one would go back to normal.

```html
<div class="status-buttons">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="statusSelect" id="statusSelect">10 Codes</button>
    </a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?>" name="statusSelect" id="statusSelect" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-99">10-99 (Panic Button)</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?>" name="statusSelect" id="statusSelect" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-8">10-8</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?>" name="statusSelect" id="statusSelect" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-7">10-7</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?>" name="statusSelect" id="statusSelect" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-6">10-6</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?>" name="statusSelect" id="statusSelect" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-97">10-97</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?>" name="statusSelect" id="statusSelect" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-23">10-23</button>
</div>
```

I'm assuming this requires some JavaScript or something of that nature. I have little experience in JavaScript and similar languages. I know basic PHP, HTML, and CSS. That's about it. And yes I know the id's are all the same. I'm going to be changing them.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML (not the PHP) and IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove the `class:selected` from all elements by looping through it, and then add the class to the current/clicked element.

Also element IDs should be unique within the entire document, you've set same ID for multiples elements...

```js
function responderChangeStatus( elem ){
  var btnEl = document.querySelectorAll('.statusSelect');
  for (var i = 0; i < btnEl.length; i++) {
      btnEl[i].classList.remove('selected');
  }
  elem.classList.add('selected');
  return;
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="status-buttons">
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<button class="btn btn-primary statusSelect"
onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" name="statusSelect" id="uniqueId01">10 Codes</button></a>
<button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?> statusSelect" name="statusSelect" id="uniqueId02" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-99">10-99 (Panic Button)</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?> statusSelect" name="statusSelect" id="uniqueId03" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-8">10-8</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?> statusSelect" name="statusSelect" id="uniqueId04" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-7">10-7</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?> statusSelect" name="statusSelect" id="uniqueId05" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-6">10-6</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?> statusSelect" name="statusSelect" id="uniqueId06" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-97">10-97</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary <?php echo $_SESSION['identifier'];?> statusSelect" name="statusSelect" id="uniqueId07" onClick="responderChangeStatus(this)" value="10-23">10-23</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to loop through all your buttons and change them back to default. You can remove all the selected class on each whether or not it exists, or use classList.contains to find for the specific button and break loop afterwards. Either way, you have to add the selected class to that one button after removing all the selected class

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.myButtons');
  for(let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    if(btns[i].classList.contains('selected')) btns[i].classList.remove('selected');
  }
myTargetButton.classList.add('selected');
```

The classes and ids are used were all mock ups, fill them up with your own css selectors