# How to switch class between eliment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I wanna switch class name **active** between button. That's mean,at a time only one button can be green by clicking. How is it possible by vanila js?

```css
.active{
    background-color:green;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button>Button1</button>
    <button class="active">Button2</button>
    <button>Button3</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use radio buttons?

Comment: `element.classList.toggle("active")` will toggle on/off. Call it on each button.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Remove the `active` class from the element that currently has it, then add the class to the event target. Use `document.querySelector()` to get the currently active element.

Comment: @mykaf That won't work. It will cause both button1 and button3 to become active.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553895/keeping-one-button-active

Comment: Because you showed no attempt to solve it yourself.

Comment: @Barmar, Of course. I somehow missed seeing button 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
First, I added a unique `id` to each button, so they could be identified in code.

```
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
<button id="button2" class="active">Button2</button>
<button id="button3">Button3</button>
```

Then I added a listener to the window’s `load` event, which gets a the list of buttons whose `id` starts with “button” and adds a listener to each one’s `click` event. The click handler is a function named `select`.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[id^=button]')
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', select)
    })
})
```

The `select` function uses `querySelector` to find the currently active button (i.e. the one with the `active` class), and remove the class from it. Then it adds the `active` class to the button that was clicked instead.

```
function select(evt) {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active')
    evt.target.classList.add('active')
}
```

Comment: If you’re just going to use `document.querySelectorAll('button[id^=button]')` anyway, why not make it a `class` instead of an `id`?

Comment: Tnx brother,  i got the idea. ❤️❤️❤️

Comment: @SebastianSimon: I take your point, but on the other hand, why _not_ use an `id`? To my thinking, if you want to identify an element, an `id` is the right thing to use. I’m ready to be shown wrong, though.